Компилятор для тестирования знаний как на codewars (React)
хочу в приложении React реализовать функционал компилятора, который проверяет написанный код с помощью заданных заранее тестов, как на codewars. Подскажите какую-нибудь библиотеку (Если отправите видеогайд буду признателен)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
